# How to insert row values that meet a condition in pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

I'm starting to learn Python and I've run into the following problem: I'm trying to join two dataframes below so that there are multiple rows containing the same names and parameters but for the entire range of temperatures.

```
    import pandas as pd
    frame1 = pd.DataFrame({'names':['bb1', 'bb2', 'bb3', 'bb4', 'bb5'],
                  'parameter1':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
                  'parameter2':['0.1', '0.2', '0.3', '0.4', '0.5']})
    frame2 = pd.DataFrame({'names':['bb1', 'bb2', 'bb3', 'bb4', 'bb5'],
                  'temperature':['300', '400', '500', '600', '700']})
```

The output should look something like this

```
        names  parameter1    parameter2    temperature
    0   bb1    1             0.1           300
    1   bb1    1             0.1           400
    ...
    5   bb2    2             0.2           300
    6   bb2    2             0.2           400
    ...
```

It feels like there should be built-in tools in pandas or itertools for that but I just can't figure it out.

I attempted using itertools.product:

```
    pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(parameters,temperature)))
```

but I can't think of a way to insert columns with parameters1 and parameters2 to match the entries in the names column. Help appreciated.

(edit) Fixed example frame1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first create a data frame that links every name to multiple temperatures and then merge it to `frame1` using `merge` function.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product
frame1 = pd.DataFrame({'names':['bb1', 'bb2', 'bb3', 'bb4', 'bb5'],
                  'parameter1':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
                  'parameter2':['0.1', '0.2', '0.3', '0.4', '0.5']})
names = ['bb1', 'bb2', 'bb3', 'bb4', 'bb5']
temperatures = ['300', '400', '500', '600', '700']
frame2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(product(names, temperatures)),
                                   columns=['names', 'temperatures'])
df = frame1.merge(frame2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.merge` take inner join on 'names'.

```
>>> pd.merge(frame1, frame2, how='inner', on = 'names')


  names parameter1 parameter2 temperature
0   bb1          1        0.1         300
1   bb1          1        0.1         121
2   bb2          2        0.2         400
3   bb3          3        0.3         500
4   bb4          4        0.4         600
5   bb5          5        0.5         700
```

Comment: This only adds the temperature column to frame1 it seems.

Comment: From the question asked, I could see that you want to merge temperature with the frame1. Please let me know if you meant something else.